# ClickOnce Deployment: Including referenced Projekts Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I have an issue with ClickOnce-Deployment, that I have not been able to solve for some time now:

I have a project in my solution, that I am deploying with ClickOnce. It references another project which has a html-file as a resource. File is set to always copy on build. When I compile in Visual Studio the html-file ends up in a folder named Resources in the bin-folder.

If I deploy the forms-project via ClickOnce the Resouces-folder is not created, when I install the deployed application. I am averting this problem, by copying the resources to the project, that is being deployed. Yet, this is quite cumbersome for project, that have a lot of resources and are deployed with several application. Surely there must be something I am missing?

Cheers
Jonas

PS: Of course the project with the resource is referenced by the deployed project!

Comment: Did you check ``Application Files...`` in the ``Publish`` tab? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx

Comment: @RandRandom: Yes, I have also read the documentation you provided. I should have mentioned that. Yet, since the project in question is not a WinForms-Project (but a Library) it has no "Publish"-Tab ...

Comment: I was talking about the ``Publish`` Tab in the ``Properties`` of your ``WinForms`` application, there you should be able to specify what files gets distributed with your published app.

Comment: @RandRandom: Yes. But I can not choose any files from the referenced project ...